# Seamless video background on page load

Tags: ajax, function, background, html5-video, transition

I'm new here and have a question for anyone who could help identifying a particular website function/technology.

This [site](https://seedlipdrinks.com/uk) uses a seamless page transition where the video background continues to play while navigating between pages. Is there some sort of timestamp function used on the video or perhaps the page content is being loaded via ajax?

Be great if someone could point me in the right direction or explain how this function could be developed!

Comment: if you look at what the site is doing via the Developer tab (network traffic and sources) you'll see each 'page' is being loaded and rendered as a fragment. It never changes the underlying page

Comment: @Offbeatmammal oh nice one! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction